# How to imagine the superconductive coherence length

Tags: superconductivity, coherence

the Ginzburg-Landau theory predicts two parameters: the penetration depth of a magnetic field into the superconductor $\lambda$ (which from agrees to London's penetration depth) and the coherence length $\xi$. The latter has the form:

$$
\xi = \sqrt{\frac{{\hbar}^2}{2m \lvert \alpha_0 (T-T_{\text{C}}) \rvert}}
$$

Here, $T_{\text{C}}$ is the critical temperature and $\alpha_0$ is some constant. I understand, the coherence length is a length over which the order parameter can fluctuate. So, a *robust* superconductor has a long coherence length. High-T superconductors have short coherence lengths and they are more sensitive to defects [1]. But with the equation above we expect $\xi$ to become large (similar to $\lambda$) when $T \rightarrow T_{\text{C}}$. This makes sense for $\lambda$: penetration becomes larger and larger and at $T = T_{\text{C}}$ the magnetic field can fully penetrate into the material (its not superconductive anymore).
But for $\xi$ this appears to be counter-intuitive to me because I would naivily assume that $\xi$ approaches 0 for the transistion between super- and normal conductor when $T = T_{\text{C}}$. Is there a way to understand this behavior apart from the equations? What does it mean for a superconductor if $\xi$ becomes infinite when $T \rightarrow T_{\text{C}}$?

[1] https://doi.org/10.3390/condmat5040077